# Apple developer account unable to get a provisioning profile set

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I've been hired as a developer to work on an existing iOS app in the store.

I have a personal AppleID developer account, not an organisation one.

Having been added as an Admin in iTunes connect, I can SEE the app that I want to make a new release for, but I cannot generate any provisioning profiles for myself.

What I HAVE done:

- created an iOS distribution certificate and downloaded and imported into Keychain access
- tried to create an App provisioning profile - says no app IDs available

This is infuriatingly complicated.  Can someone please spell out what I need to do to be able to make a release version of the app using the existing AppId, bundle identifier etc?

I don't want to release this as a brand new app+identifier.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They suppose to give you a permission to their apple member center. Thats different than the itunesconnect permission. When they do that inside the member center you can switch accounts and you will be able to see the app id you wanted.